# Laravel: How to redirect to subdomain using a Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, dns

The function of my program is to create a subdomain/subdirectory. I have a directories table, once a user will create a subdomain it redirects to its subdomain.

Example:
My site is http://dns.dev, if I will create a subdomain 'test' and click the button 'Create directory', then it redirect to http://test.dns.dev

I have this route for subdomains.

```
Route::post('/create', 'DirectoryController@create');
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.dns.dev'], function () {
        Route::get('/', function ($subdomain) {
            return $subdomain;
        });
    });
```

In my controller,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Redirect;

use App\Directory;

class DirectoryController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $directory = new Directory;
        $directory->domain = $request->subdomain;
        $directory->status = "pending";
        $directory->save();

        //redirect to $request->subdomain . '.dns.dev/' 
        //something like that


    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$url = 'http://yourdomainname.com';
return Redirect::to($url);
```

Comment: Ok it's working. Do you know how to redirect it to the route ('/') . I tried it but it redirects to http://test3.dns.dev/dashboard   (XAMPP dashboard page), it should redirect to http://test3.dns.dev/project/public/

Comment: Ok I will just edit and add /project/public/ in the controller. Edit your answer please, add http:// so I can upvote it correctly.